# sort -V on Mac OS not working?

Tags: linux, macos, sorting

Sort -V works on Linux (which means natural sort of version numbers within text) and looks like there is no -V option on MacOS? Any alternatives?

regards,
Lin

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394536/how-to-simulate-sort-v-on-mac-osx

Comment: Thanks @Ouroborus, tried both solutions mentioned in the page, the solution using sed command does not work if there are more than 2 digits in version number, rudix package look does not contain sort function from this list => http://rudix.org/packages/index.html, if you have any further thoughts, it will be great. Vote up for your reply. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your list looks like this-

```
cat list
6.3.1.1
6.3.1.10
6.3.1.11
6.3.1.2
6.3.1.3
5.2.3.1
5.2.4.2
5.2.3.2

sort -n -t. -k1 -k4 list
5.2.3.1
5.2.3.2
5.2.4.2
6.3.1.1
6.3.1.2
6.3.1.3
6.3.1.10
6.3.1.11
```

Comment: It doesn't work. `echo -e '2.7\n2.10\n2.1' | sort -n -t. -k1 -k4` prints '2.1 2.10 2.7'

Comment: @Jongwook Choi - The answer is a demonstration using a field separator and changing the sort order with key values. The answer is not static and requires that you know the values that you are sorting. In your case, `echo -e '2.7\n2.10\n2.1' | LC_ALL=C sort -g -t. -k2,1`